# If $\left(\sqrt2\right)^x + \left(\sqrt3\right)^x = \left(\sqrt{13}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}$ then the number of values of $x$ is?

Tags: exponential-function

> If $\left(\sqrt2\right)^x + \left(\sqrt3\right)^x = \left(\sqrt{13}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}$ then the number of values of $x$ is?

It is an exponent topic question tried squaring method but couldn't get to the right answer. The answer is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$(4/13)^{x/4}+(9/13)^{x/14}=1$$

Now clearly $x/4=1$ is a solution

As the left hand side is monotonic decreasing, there can be no more solution

This approach can be applied for

$$(\cos^2t)^n+(\sin^2t)^n=1$$

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity (but too long for a comment).*

For your specific problem, as @lab bhattacharjee answered, the problem is *"quite simple"* because $2^2+3^2=13$.

Making the problem more general, suppose that you want $x$ such that
$$\left(\sqrt 2\right)^x+\left(\sqrt 3\right)^x=\left(\sqrt k\right)^{\frac x 2}\implies  2^{x/2}+3^{x/2}=k^{x/4}$$ This means that you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=k^{x/4}-\big[ 2^{x/2}+3^{x/2}\big]$$ which is not very pleasant (have a look at its plot). However, if you consider the function
$$g(x)=\frac x 4 \log(k)-\log\big[ 2^{x/2}+3^{x/2}\big]$$ it is *almost* the problem of the intersection of two straight lines. Using Taylor expansion built around $x=0$, you will have
$$g(x)=\log (2)+\frac{1}{4} x (\log (3)+\log (2)-\log (k))+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which gives as an *estimate*
$$x_0=\frac {4 \,\log(2)}{\log \left(\frac{k}{6}\right)}$$ For $k=13$, this gives $x_0 \sim 3.58591$ This is in fact the result of the first iteration of Newton method.

Performing a second iteration would give $x_1 \sim 3.99515$

Comment: I delete my answer and upvote your. +1 and excuse me very much. I'm really sorry about your invalidity.

Comment: @Sebastiano. Please, undelete your answer and add what I asked you. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Don't worry...here there are many users also of TeX.SE. With all sincerity I didn't understand English as I often do and I deleted it both for your serious and important reason and that your answers are beautiful. With esteem my greetings.